# How do you let database automatically proceed operations if some timestamp attributes are equal to current time?

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, relational-database

If each tuple in a table in a database has a timestamp attribute and a user id, you want to send some data to the user once the current time is equal to the timestamp in db. How do you do it?

Comment: You will need to use some scheduler service in addition the the database. When yo insert such a record, also update the scheduler. You may be able to do this with a trigger, but it's probably better to do it in application code (and decouple the scheduler from the database).

Comment: Thanks. So does the scheduler thread need to be constantly running and checking all the timestamps? And we cannot store all the timestamps in memory if there are too many of them. Or having the scheduler constantly fetch db is not efficient either.

Comment: The scheduler only needs to know the next timestamp and wake itself up at that time to do work and to figure out the next next timestamp. You should prepare a searchable list for that purpose (but doesn't have to fit in memory).

Comment: Right, but if the scheduler thread is not constant running, how can it wake itself up when it is the time. And each time when the scheduler is working, it has to fetch db to get the next timestamp. The fetching process may take a bit long and we may miss some timestamps that are right after the current timestamp but before the fetching is done. I guess we can have a reasonable amount of next timestamps in memory to avoid this?